# Prevent rapply from treating data.frame as a list

Tags: r

I have a list of lists of `data.frame`s.  A simple way to apply a function to the deepest elements of nested list is with `rapply`.  However, `rapply` is treating the `data.frame`s as lists, and thus, attempting to apply the function to every column of each `data.frame`.  A similar question was asked about `mapply` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497752/r-how-can-mapply-take-data-frame-as-a-whole), but the solution doesn't work for `rapply`.  Is there any way to prevent `rapply` from treating the `data.frame`s as lists?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813353/running-rapply-on-lists-of-dataframes) is pretty close to a duplicate. At a minimum, it should be helpful.